# How can I convert an int to a generic type containing complex128 in Go?

Tags: go, generics, complex-numbers

I cannot work out how to convert an `int` to a generic type containing `complex128`. Here is an example which doesn't compile unless the `complex128` is commented out:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type val interface {
    int64 | float64 | complex128
}

func f[V val](a, b V) (c V) {
    q := calc()
    return a * b * V(q)
}

func calc() int {
    // lengthy calculation that returns an int
    return 1
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", f(int64(1), int64(2)))
}
```

This is simplified from a much larger calculation. I've tried using a switch but every syntax I have attempted seems to meet resistance of one kind or another.

How can I multiply `a` and `b` with an integer?

I have tried using a switch on the type of the return variable such as `any(c).(type)` but for example if I have `case complex128:` then it refuses to allow the `complex` builtin since it doesn't return a `V`.

Without the `complex128` the above will compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works but it needs to list every type in the `switch` statement:

```golang
func f[V val](a, b V) (c V) {
    q := calc()

    var temp any
    switch any(c).(type) {
    case complex128:
        temp = complex(float64(q), 0)
    case int64:
        temp = int64(q)
    default:
        temp = float64(q)
    }
    return a * b * (temp.(V))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zeke, that was almost exactly what my code looked like except for the `var temp any` and `temp.(V)` at the end, so I only had to add two lines.

Comment: Please consider @blackgreen's answer. `If you have to specialize the function with type switches to force it to work, you are better off simply not using generics at all`. The solution in my answer is error-prone. Imagine that a new type is added to the `val` constraint, and you forgot to list it in the func `f`, it panicks if the new type is used.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The current solution seems OK so far but I'll keep that in mind. I actually have a `float64` in my `switch` not a `default`.

Comment: If it's called with a type that is not listed, it panicks with the error like this: `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not [the_name_of_the_new_type]`. I can not think of a unit test to catch it. Maybe you should add a comment to remind the future you. ^_^

Answer (score 4):

As stated, your issue can't be solved with actually generic code. The presence of `complex128` in the union excludes a clean conversion from `int` to `V`.

Conversions that involve type parameters work only if the conversion is valid for all types in the type parameter type set, and complex types aren't convertible to other non-complex numeric types. The [language spec states](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions)

> A non-constant value x can be converted to type T in any of these cases:
>
> [...]
>
> - x's type and T are both integer or floating point types.
> - x's type and T are both complex types.

While integer and floats can be converted to each other, complex types can't.

Therefore generics don't work here. If you have to specialize the function with type switches to force it to work, you are better off simply not using generics at all.

Note that the function would nicely work with an untyped constant. It would be implicitly converted to whatever type is required by the expression:

```
func f[V val](a, b V) (c V) {
    return a * b * 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Generally speaking I think that generics were a good solution for the problem I am solving but I had missed the method which Zeke explained above.

Comment: @SuzuHirose yeah I have a high bar for introducing generics in my code base where the code isn't actually generic. Zeke's code works just fine if you are okay with that kind of design.